# HTML CSS why a set divs not start new line

Tags: html, css, newline

`Divs` inside `Div` (`id="icons"`) not starting new line **(like Windows 7 icons)**

I want the `divs` inside `div` with `id="icons"` don't start a new line it flows vertically. Why not start new line?

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y7ktkd2/)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#icons {
 position: fixed;
 background: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
#icons1 {
 position: relative;
 background: blue;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons2 {
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons3 {
 position: relative;
 background: lime;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons4 {
 position: relative;
 background: pink;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons5 {
 position: relative;
 background: purple;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons6 {
 position: relative;
 background: blue;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons7 {
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons8 {
 position: relative;
 background: lime;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons9 {
 position: relative;
 background: pink;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
#icons10 {
 position: relative;
 background: purple;
 width: 20%;
 height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="desktop">

<div id="icons">
<div id="icons1"></div>
<div id="icons2"></div>
<div id="icons3"></div>
<div id="icons4"></div>
<div id="icons5"></div>
<div id="icons6"></div>
<div id="icons7"></div>
<div id="icons8"></div>
<div id="icons9"></div>
<div id="icons10"></div>
<div id="icons1"></div>
<div id="icons2"></div>
<div id="icons3"></div>
<div id="icons4"></div>
<div id="icons5"></div>
<div id="icons6"></div>
<div id="icons7"></div>
<div id="icons8"></div>
<div id="icons9"></div>
<div id="icons10"></div>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Please avoid decoration to the question post like `/////` there may be chances of members voting to close the question for being unclear.

Answer (score 2):

A DIV by default is a display type of 'block' and therefore forces in the line break.

You can get around this by using `display: inline-block;` in your CSS like so:

```
#icons1 {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#icons2 {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* etc */
```

You can add this in at the higher level (Icons) but if you're trying to do Windows style then you probably want more control over what and where breaks occur.

(hopefully I interpreted your question correctly!)

Answer (score 1):

Change the display type on those icon divs.

```
#icons div {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0y7ktkd2/1/